# Show maximum symbols in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, each

How to show maximin 250 symbols? For **post.description**

> 

```
<% @microposts.each do |post| %>
    <% a = post.had %>
    <% b = post.needs.to_f %>
    <% count = (a/b)*100 %>
      <div class="col-md-12 post card-1 card-3">
        <h3 class="pad-h3"><%= post.title %> <text class="needs"> Needs  <%= post.needs %>$</text></h3>
        <div class="row pad">
          <div class="col-md-6"><a href="/help/id<%= post.id %>"><img class="img2" src="<%= post.image1 %>">
            <h3 class="fun"><%= count %>% Funded</h3>
          </a></div>
          <div class="col-md-6"><p><%= post.description %></p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"><a href="/help/id<%= post.id %>" class="butt2" data-wipe="Show more information">Show more information</a></div>
       </div>
  <% end %>
```

Sometext SometextSometextSometextSometext Sometextv Sometextv vvvvvvSometextSometextSometextSometextSometextSometextSometextSometextSometextSometextSometextSome  textSometextS dometext SometextSometextSometextSomete xtSometextSometextSometextSometextSometextSometext

Comment: The term "[symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Symbol.html)" has specific meaning in Ruby. Do you mean _characters_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has [`truncate` text helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate):

```
<%= truncate post.description, length: 250 %>
```